# Images with Accent Mark Characters in Filename Not Showing

Tags: channel-images

I've done everything that I can think of to fix this issue and I can't seem to get an image to output when it has an accent mark in the file name. The same image will show when an à is changed to a. The character set is set to UTF-8 on our installation of EE. Any suggestions?

We are using a third-party plugin called Photomule and inside photomule_model.php I thought this change would work:

```
$filename  = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^0-9a-z\-\_\.\é\à\á\è\ç]/i', '', $this->path_info['filename']));
```

This image is also inside of a channel field called Feature Content with the channel field name gencon_feature which is inside of a Matrix.

Currently using v2.7.2 of Expression Engine.